# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long using Streamlit

Tags: python, upload, streamlit

I have been trying to use StreamLit for a little website project I have going on and I keep getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

Here is the coding

```
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose a file", accept_multiple_files=True)
for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.read()
    s = bytes_data.decode("UTF-8")
    SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")
    loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(s)
    documents = loader.load_data()
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents)
    index.save_to_disk('index.json')
    question = st.text_input("What do you want me to do with the file uploaded?")
    response = index.query(question)
    st.write(response)
```

Here is the full error:

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/indextest/streamlit_app.py", line 17, in <module>
    loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(s)
File ".modules/file.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.input_files = self._add_files(self.input_dir)
File ".modules/file.py", line 81, in _add_files
    input_files = sorted(input_dir.iterdir())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1160, in iterdir
    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
```

Comment: How long are the filenames you're uploading?

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: @CarolineFrasca that is all that it gave me

Comment: @Camol Can you give the complete name of the file you are uploading?

Comment: That isn't a full error message. Regardless, have you tried making the filename shorter?

Comment: @vvvvv It is reading all of the information inside of the file as the file name for some reason.

Comment: @CarolineFrasca ^

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the entire content of the file as an argument to `SimpleDirectoryReader`. However, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/jerryjliu/gpt_index/blob/main/gpt_index/readers/file/base.py#L34) of the `SimpleDirectoryReader` class, the first argument should be a path to a directory:

> input_dir (str): Path to the directory.

You should store the `uploaded_files` inside a folder, and then give this folder as an argument to `SimpleDirectoryReader` like this:

```py
import os

save_folder = "files"
if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
    os.makedirs(save_folder)

uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose a file", accept_multiple_files=True)
for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.read()
    s = bytes_data.decode("UTF-8")
    
    # save the file
    with open(f"{save_folder}/{uploaded_file.name}", "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

# Then, once you have stored the files, load the SimpleDirectoryReader
SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")
loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(save_folder)
documents = loader.load_data()
```